How can I visit my self hosted web app from the public internet?
Background
I have a web app that I've been building and testing locally.  I've deployed it to a server that I own, which is running here in my house.  The server is connected via ethernet to my home router.  I pay Xfinity for a normal residential plan, in which I have a single public IP address.  On the server I have installed Proxmox, I've created VMs, deployed my code, it runs and I can view my web app over my LAN ip 10.0.0.26:.  That's great.
Problem
I need to be able to access this application from the public internet.  How can I achieve this?
My Current Thoughts and Questions
( This is where I need help, so please forgive me for my ignorance.)

During my research in forums I've read that I can set up forwarding so that public traffic going to my IP address is forwarded my app's address/port within my local network. However people claimed that this could be dangerous, as a mistake could potentially lock me out and brick my system. Some also mentioned that I would lose internet access within my home network.

Could a cloud provider help? I don't know if this is even possible, but could I use AWS services to purchase an Elastic IP or a domain with Route 53, that I could then enter into Proxmox for use with these VMs running on my home server?

Is there a service like NORD or something else, that I could use to purchase additional IP addresses? Would this work for my use case?

Is this easily set up in Proxmox and do I just not know what tf I'm doing? If so, please point me in the right direction.


Constraints

I need to be able to maintain normal access to the internet within my household. Laptop, phone, other devices, etc.
I don't need a risky solution where if I make a mistake I'm going to lock myself out.
I'm willing to pay for a service if that's necessary, but hopefully it's not too expensive, maybe a max of $50 per month.

Any advice, direction, documentation, youtube videos would be very much appreciated. Thank you!
I've been looking through tons of forums and documentation.  I'm not sure what to try. I don't know what would actually work. I feel like this isn't an uncommon question, but I can't seem to find a straight answer.

Port forwarding is easy and simple, and I've never heard of anyone screwing up like you described.

I really have no idea. That's just what I saw in forums. It's also likely that I misunderstood what I read.  This is new to me.


Port forwarding

Port forwarding is the easiest and most straightforward solution to accomplish what you want. You simply host your application at a specific port on your server. Then you configure your router to forward a port (usually the same one, but depending on the router you could choose to be a different one) to the server. Then you can access your site using a combination of your external IP address and port.

Cloud provider

You could just choose to host your app in the cloud. AWS and Azure both have free hosting options. Or you could host a reverse proxy in the cloud. Or purchase a domain name to point to your home's external IP.
Purchasing a domain name doesn't absolve you of the need to forward the port in your router to the correct machine. All it does is register a hostname with DNS providers that says if someone tries to access your hostname, that should resolve to your IP address. It can be convenient however, as you won't need to remember your IP when accessing it externally. And if your home's IP were to ever change, you'd just update it with the place you purchased the DNS from, and you wouldn't need to change any other configuration.

Is there a service like NORD or something else, that I could use to purchase additional IP addresses? Would this work for my use case?

Your ISP assigns your external IP address. No, adding more IP's won't help. Even if there were a way to get more IP's, you'd still need to forward a port to allow the traffic to come into your server, unless you add an extra NIC to your computer and didn't have a NAT layer in between you and the ISP.

Is this easily set up in Proxmox and do I just not know what tf I'm doing?

There's not really much to do in Proxmox other than make sure you're listening on the proper IP and that the port it's listening on matches what you had your router forward traffic to.

I need to be able to maintain normal access to the internet within my household. Laptop, phone, other devices, etc.

You can forward ports without affecting any of the other network traffic.

I don't need a risky solution where if I make a mistake I'm going to lock myself out.

Great, port forwarding is easy and there's plenty of guides out there.

I'm willing to pay for a service if that's necessary, but hopefully it's not too expensive, maybe a max of $50 per month.

You don't need to pay anything to get up and going. Though if you wanted to not host it at your own home, $50 goes a long ways towards paying for cloud hosting.

thank you so much for your comprehensive response. I will try port forwarding.

I'm going to try it this weekend. I'll post here what I end up doing and I'll post a process
